# Copy all contacts from HTC Desire HD to my google account

Tags: contacts, sync, google-account, htc-desire-hd

I'm trying to sync all my contacts from my HTC Desire HD to my google account but I can't see them anywhere in my google account. I have already found several tutorials on the the internet but still can't make my contacts visible in google account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this the old-fashioned way if you want to do one-time sync only:

- Go to Contacts and export to SD card. This will create a handy [vCard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vcard) file that will reside in the root of your SD card. Most often this will be `00001.vcf` or some such.
- From a desktop computer, go to [Gmail contacts](https://mail.google.com/mail/?shva=1#contacts) and choose `Import` from the menu above.

From the desktop you can add and edit your contacts much more easily than you would on the phone. However, I found syncing to be unreliable sometimes, especially with HTC Sence (I had the stock ROM previously on my HTC Desire) -- I had to deal with duplicate contacts and mysteriously vanishing phone numbers on a few occasions.